# NodeRPCConnection.java instead NodeRPCConnection.kt

Tags: corda

I want to connect RPC connection using java instead of kotlin. In corda 4.0 they have given using kotlin but I need it in java.

I have tried using java but its not working...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/example/")
```

Comment: Formatted the code

Answer (score 0):

below code snippet from WebFlux module which connects to corda node using RPC:

```
@Component
public class NodeRPCConnection implements AutoCloseable {
// The host of the node we are connecting to.
@Value("${config.rpc.host}")
private String host;
// The RPC port of the node we are connecting to.
@Value("${config.rpc.username}")
private String username;
// The username for logging into the RPC client.
@Value("${config.rpc.password}")
private String password;
// The password for logging into the RPC client.
@Value("${config.rpc.port}")
private int rpcPort;

private CordaRPCConnection rpcConnection;
private CordaRPCOps proxy;



@PostConstruct
public void initialiseNodeRPCConnection() {
    NetworkHostAndPort rpcAddress = new NetworkHostAndPort(host, rpcPort);
    CordaRPCClient rpcClient = new CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress);
    rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password);
    proxy = rpcConnection.getProxy();
}

@PreDestroy
public void close() {
    rpcConnection.notifyServerAndClose();
}

public CordaRPCOps getProxy() {
    return proxy;
}
}
```